# Can i get the object of an application with CGI Ajax request?

Tags: html, ajax, apache, http, cgi

I have a HTML file which will send a POST request to CGI through Ajax HTTP request and waiting for a response Text . In CGI script , i am calling a application which will change my network and connected to another network ( like VPN ) .

I am facing problem like , Whenever i send a POST request to CGI script , it will execute the application and change the network . So i can not get request back (Network changed) . But i need the status of the application (connected or disconnected) . For that i am sending another request with a time out to fetch the status of the application .

I am creating a object for the application inside the CGI . So for the first request it will create the object for running the application . So after time out , when i send the second request , it will again create another object . But i need to get the status of first object . Can i get this status as response text through second CGI request ? Means i need the previous object and it's status

Any idea ? will cookies help me to do this process ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The first request shall store whatever you need (or just the whole object) from the first object somewhere accessible (files, databases, whatever) by subsequent requests. I don't think cookies will do because you expect the first request to terminate due to timeout, meaning you will never ever get the cookie (it should be in the response header) anyway.

Comment: So should i store the whole object inside database ? and access this object with next object ?

Comment: doesn't have to, but it's an option. practically anything that can be shared across processes of different lifetime. whole object or not, it's up to you. only you knows what needs to be shared.